# Iterate over multiple folders at once

Tags: python, filesystems

I am looking to loop over my data folders categorized by year
eg.
[image]

Example file name: EastSales_20200101_house.txt

Rather than hardcoding through each year folder path one by one, what would be an alternative for looping through the year folders and categorize the data in the year folders by month.

[image]

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime
import os

my_data = Path("/Users/me/Documents/my_data")
#check if file exists
for file in my_data.iterdir():
  if file.is_file():
    directory = file.parent
    extension = file.suffix
    old_name  = file.stem
    region,old_date,categ = old_name.split('_')
     #rename file
    old_date = datetime.strptime(old_date,"%Y%m%d")
    date = datetime.strftime(old_date, "%Y%m%d")
    new_date = f'{date}{extension}'

    #categorize by year
    year = datetime.strftime(old_date, "%Y")
    new_path = my_data.joinpath(year)
    
    #check if folder exists
    if not new_path.exists():
      new_path.mkdir()

    #create new path in directory
    new_file_path = new_path.joinpath(newfile)
    file.replace(new_file_path)

# Currently looping over months by hardcoding path
my_data_2020 = Path("/Users/me/Documents/my_data/2020")
#check if file exists
for file in my_data_2020.iterdir():
  if file.is_file():
    directory_2020 = file.parent
    extension = file.suffix
    old_name_2020  = file.stem

     #rename file
    old_date_2020 = datetime.strptime(old_date_2020,"%Y%m%d")
    date_2020 = datetime.strftime(old_date_2020, "%Y%m%d")
    new_date_2020 = f'{date_2020}{extension}'

    #categorize by month
    month = datetime.strftime (old_date_2020, "%m)
    new_path_2020 = my_data.joinpath(year)
    
    #check if folder exists
    if not new_path_2020.exists():
      new_path_2020.mkdir()

    #create new path in directory
    new_file_path_2020 = new_path_2020.joinpath(newfile_2020)
    file.replace(new_file_path_2020)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "at once"?

Comment: Have you considered multithreading?

Comment: What do you mean by "hardcoding through each year folder"?

Comment: @martineau I mean I have defined the path for the year 2020 
my_data_2020, similar for the year 2021 the path is for folder 2021. I was looking to loop over the folders rather than writing the path name every time. Thanks!

Comment: All right. What does the first snippet of code have to do your question? When asking questions here, it's usually best to provide a [mre] and leave out as much unrelated stuff out as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The actual walk through the directories works as you have coded it. If you replace the contents of the inner loop with a simple print statement you can see that each file is found:

```
import os
rootdir = 'C:/Users/sid/Desktop/test'
    
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(subdir, file))
```